# Trigger not working on Update sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I wrote a simple stored procedure which is supposed to update an existing table a based on another table b that is continually having values added.

I want the stored procedure to run every time a value is added to b.

I wrote a simple trigger that I think should work but it is not working. The trigger just executes the stored procedure every time there is an insert or update in b.

Here is what the trigger looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerTest]
ON [dbo].[BELL_DPRA2_locates_fact]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE dbo.Test
END
```

If I run the procedure separately, it works fine. It updates the first table. 
But If I leave it waiting for the trigger to act, nothing happens. Table b in the meantime is having data stream in every second. Please help me find the what the problem is.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurDate DATE
    SET @CurDate = CAST((SELECT GETDATE()) AS DATE); 

    MERGE INTO dbo.DPRA2_Export T
    USING (SELECT
               CAST(risk_date AS DATE) as "Dated", 
               COUNT(risk_score) AS "Risk2" 
           FROM 
               dbo.BELL_DPRA2_locates_fact  
           WHERE 
               Risk_Score = 2 
               AND CAST(Risk_Date AS DATE) = @CurDate
           GROUP BY 
               CAST(risk_date AS DATE)) S ON T.Risk_Date_Day = S.Dated

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET T.Risk2 = S.Risk2

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Risk_Date_Day, Risk2) 
        VALUES (@CurDate, S.Risk2);
END
```

Comment: You should write a trigger that actually **references** the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables - those hold the values that were **actually** inserted or changed. Your current procedure just basically merges **everything** every time a single row is inserted - not very efficient !

Comment: It is actually merging one row of data based on current date. In the procedure, it is getting the current date everytime it runs and only runs for those value. In the table it inserts into, it just updates the very top row which corresponds to current date. 

Anyways, can you give me a general example of how **references** will work in the trigger? I am still a bit confused...thanks!